# What to do about [tag:kernel] with multiple meanings

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

In trying to do some tag cleanup for OS related tags I came upon the [kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel) tag.  This tag has at least three different meanings in the context of cs.se.

1. The [operating-systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems) sense, in which the *kernel* refers to the central software component that manages, schedules and controls access to resources in general, and to input/output devices more specifically.  [Here is the definition from the SO kernel tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kernel/info).
2. The [machine-learning](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) sense in which a *kernel* refers (I think) to an multi-dimensional operator mapping from one space to another.  [Here is the definition from the CrossValidated kernel tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/kernel/info).
3. The [parametrized-complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parametrized-complexity) sense in which a *kernel* refers (I think) to an algorithm input that has been preprocessed into a simpler form that can be fed to an already existing algorithm.
4. There are several more meanings, one in image processing (although dsp.se does not have such a tag) and one in gpgpu programming  (which is probably not relevant to us.)

There are currently 17 questions tagged [kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel).  5 of them are from the os.se migration that happened earlier today.  8 more are existing questions that are also tagged [operating-systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems), 2 more are existing questions that are not also tagged [operating-systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems), but should be.  Finally the last 2 are tagged [machine-learning](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning).

There are several possibilities for what to do.  One is to create three different tags [os-kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-kernel), [kernel-functions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-functions), [kernelization](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernelization) for the three different uses respectively.  Another is to use [kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel) in the machine-learning sense, and then use the tag wiki to direct operating systems kernel questions to use [operating-systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/operating-systems) and parametrized complexity questions to use [parametrized-complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parametrized-complexity).  (And there are doubtlessly other ways to handle it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend introducing the two tags [os-kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-kernel) and [kernel-functions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-functions),
and then introducing a tag synonym [kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel) -> [os-kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-kernel).

I do not think we need a special tag for "kernel" in the context of parametrized complexity.  That's a niche topic and I don't think we need such a specialized tag.  As far as I can tell, we don't currently have any questions like that.

I definitely do not recommend using [kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel) to mean the machine-learning sense.  We currently have 17 existing questions tagged [kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel).  15 of them relate to the OS sense.  2 of them relate to the machine learning sense.  0 of them relate to the parametrized complexity sense.  If we have to pick a single meaning for [kernel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel), it should clearly be the OS meaning, as that is far more common.

Comment: I agree that [tag:kernel] for the machine learning sense would be bad: a large fraction of computer scientists will recognize "kernel" as an operating systems term and a much smaller fraction as a machine learning term. If [tag:kernel] were to mean only the machine learning sense, a large fraction of questions about OS kernels will need to be retagged. (Admittedly, that's a small number of questions in total but principle of least surprise and all that.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the best tag for the machine-learning version is, but I am in favor of ditching [tag:kernel] completely and using more clear tags for all occurrences of the term.

Comment: Implemented as of September 25th.